# copy changed files from jenkins build

Tags: php, git, jenkins

I'm trying to get jenkins to deploy the files that changed since the last commit.
Now I found a script for doing this [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/A+PHP+script+to+copy+only+updated+files)

after looking at it and changing the things accordingly I had the following script left.

```
<?php
$pathProject = "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite";
$pathLog = $pathProject."/builds/".$argv[1]."/changelog.xml";
$pathSource = $pathProject."/workspace/";
$pathDestination = $pathProject."/publish";

if (file_exists($pathLog)) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($pathLog);
    $numberOfAuthors = count($xml->logentry);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfAuthors; $i++){

      $numberOfAuthorFiles = count($xml->logentry[$i]->paths->path);
      for($j = 0; $j < $numberOfAuthorFiles; $j++){

        $arrayPath[] = $xml->logentry[$i]->paths->path[$j];
      }
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayPath); $i++){

      $path1 = $pathSource . $arrayPath[$i];
      $path2 = $pathDestination . $arrayPath[$i];

      system("cp $path1 $path2");

    }
}
else {

  exit("Failed to open $pathLog.");
}

?>
```

I created a directory in my job named "publish" where all the changed files should be changed to.

However when I run the script I get the following output

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/builds/25/changelog.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:0
PHP   2. simplexml_load_file() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:9
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): commit dc6f1966e845c408041b126967b2ca27057934bd in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:0
PHP   2. simplexml_load_file() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:9
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:0
PHP   2. simplexml_load_file() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:9
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php on line 10
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:0
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: arrayPath in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php on line 21
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mysite/workspace/build_script.php:0
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong and what I should do to fix this? I'm kinda new to php but I figured maybe there is something outdated about the script?

Here is the changelog.xml. I'm running jenkins on an ubuntu server so I ssh'ed to the server and opened the changelog in the vim editor

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's complaining that your `changelog.xml` is not valid xml. Can you post that?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I added a screenshot of the changelog

Comment: That's not your changelog, that's your git log. Let's see `cat changelog.xml`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII That actually is the changelog.xml I just checked again to be sure and the screenshot I posted is 100% sure what is inside of my changelog.xml for a certain build

Comment: Then that's your problem because it's not [XML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), which is the cause of the PHP error.

Comment: I don't use Jenkins, so it would be helpful if you could explain the process that generates this file.